# Slight padding issues regarding tables nested in Divs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently in the process of finishing a website which required tables to perfectly align several images and links to various photos, which are all nested withing a table. This table is within a div, inside a custom user control (.ascx)

Now on my main page, I have a logo for the website , which is nested in a centre tag

```
 <center>
    <div class="SizeToAlignment">
      <img src="Images/Master_Images/logo.gif" style="width: 958px; height: 100%;" alt="Heading" />
    </div>
 </center>
 <center>
    <div>
      <uc1:TablePics ID="TablePics1" runat="server" />
    </div>
 </center>
```

The end product causes the LogoDiv to misalign with the usercontrol TablePics1 (containing my tables of links and images) by 1 single pixel (to the left).

I do not want to resize my logo. Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purposes, try this:

```
<div class="SizeToAlignment" style="padding-left:1px;">
    ...
</div>
```

If this resolves the issue, remove this style attribute and add the padding-left rule to the SiteToAlignment class in your style sheet.

Comment: the cookie crumbled hard there, and it seemed to have been out by 2 pixels. Definitely aligned now. thanks!

Comment: CSS stuff can be a real PITA ;-)

Comment: no kidding :O I'm actually a windows forms developer >< But my job requires me to make asp.net websites, so I'm still a trainee

Comment: For resolving CSS probs, the Web Dev Toolbar in Firefox is your best friend ;-)

Comment: im using Firefox 4 :?  where can I find this toolbar? is it a plugin? or should I get my lazy ass over to google :P

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/ This will allow you to "view style information"... big help.